# How to combine dataframe rows, and combine their string column into list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
index  name      A
0      one       a
1      two       a
2      one       b
3      two       a
```

How can I merge rows with identical 'name' so that the new column A is a list of all the A associated with each 'name'? So, the output would be:

```
index  name      A
0      one       [a, b]
1      two       [a]
```

Comment: Check the duplicated link, only need to add `drop_duplicate` before groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Answer

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
    'A' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
})

df['COLUMN_MERGE'] = df['A'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['B'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby(['name'])['COLUMN_MERGE'].apply(set).apply(list).reset_index(name = 'Distinct_Merge')
```

Comment: what if we have more than 'A' column, how to merge them, please?? @ArchAngelPwn

Comment: I updated my answer, but this is a rough simplified example, if you wanted to get more in depth you would have to provide more details.